# Django model form - Exclude a field that has no model field

Tags: django, django-forms, django-models

I have a simple model form what I use through the admin interface. Some of my model fields store datas that require a bit more time to calculate (they come from other sites). So I decided to put an extra boolean field to the form to decide to crawl these datas again or not.

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    update_values = forms.BooleanField(required=False) #this field has no model field

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

This extra field doesn't exist in the model because only the form needs it.

The **problem** is that I only want it to appear if it's an existing record in the database.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.instance.pk is None:
        #remove that field somehow
```

I tried nearly everything. Exclude it, delete the variable but nothing wants to work. I also tried dynamically add the field if self.instance.pk is exists but that didn't work too.

Any idea how to do the trick?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could subclass the form and add the extra field in the subclass:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

class MyUpdateModelForm(MyModelForm):
    update_values = forms.BooleanField(required=False) #this field has no model field

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

You can then override the `get_form` method of your admin, which is passed the current instance: `get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs)`

Comment: Thanks man, seems its working now! In **get_form** I had to do the following: 
`if obj and obj.pk:
    self.form = MyModelUpdateForm
else:
    self.form = MyModelForm`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than removing the field in `__init__` if instance.pk is not None, how about adding it if it *is* None? Remove the class-level declaration and just change the logic:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance and self.instance.pk is not None:
            self.fields['update_values'] = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

Comment: I already tried this. Not sure why but the admin interface doesn't display it in this case.